# "Block" UI Thread till Backgroundworker finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, gif

I have a Backgroundworker and I want to display a loading gif till the worker has finished.

My problem is that I cannot use

```
while(worker.IsBusy)
    Thread.Sleep(50);
```

because that blocks the UI Thread and my GIF from updating it's frames.

Same problem occurs when using an *AutoResetEvent* and `myAutoResetEvent.WaitOne();`

Do you have any idea how to wait for the Backgroundworker to finish and still be able to display a GIF?

Comment: Why using a BackgroundWorker if you want to wait until loading ends?

Comment: The entire purpose of using a BackgroundWorker is to **prevent** the UI from blocking. Why on Earth would you want to intentionally cause the problem that the background thread is intended to prevent? You need to rethink the issue, because starting a thread to prevent blocking and then intentionally blocking just isn't proper design.

Comment: Using a BackgroundWorker because I want to display a loading GIF while the code is executed.
And if I don't use a BackgroundWorker for the work the UI will freeze and show no loading GIF.
But I want this gif to be displayed while the Worker is working.

Comment: You could have your background worker set a property which parts of your UI binds to to know that most of the UI should be disabled, and you also use that property to know when to show the GIF in another task/background worker. This way the background worker is doing stuff but your window doesn't freeze while also showing a GIF.

Comment: Don't edit answers into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of the `BackgroundWorker` is to allow the UI to continue running.

And, you specifically want a GIF to continue to update with the `BackgroundWorker` is running.

So it's a perfect solution.

Clearly, though, you want the UI to be "non-iteractive" while the `BackgroundWorker` is running. Well, there's a fairly basic way to do that.

Here it is:

```
    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveButton.Enabled = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Basically, you just disable the controls that you don't want to user to interact with and re-enable them when the `BackgroundWorker` is done.